Write Parquet file with GraalVM native image
I try to write a parquet file in Java with org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter using a GraalVM native image.
My code works fine in Java, but after compiling with native image, when I run the code I have this issue:
PAR1Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.plain.BooleanPlainValuesWriter.<init>(BooleanPlainValuesWriter.java:38)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.factory.DefaultV1ValuesWriterFactory.getBooleanValuesWriter(DefaultV1ValuesWriterFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.factory.DefaultV1ValuesWriterFactory.newValuesWriter(DefaultV1ValuesWriterFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.factory.DefaultValuesWriterFactory.newValuesWriter(DefaultValuesWriterFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.newValuesWriter(ParquetProperties.java:167)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterBase.<init>(ColumnWriterBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.<init>(ColumnWriterV1.java:43)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.createColumnWriter(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:50)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.<init>(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:125)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.<init>(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:44)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.newColumnWriteStore(ParquetProperties.java:220)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.initStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:116)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.<init>(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:101)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:301)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:702)
    at xxx.main(XXX.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: factory
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.Packer.getStaticField(Packer.java:103)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.Packer.getIntPackerFactory(Packer.java:87)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.Packer.<clinit>(Packer.java:107)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: factory
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.checkField(DynamicHub.java:1041)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getField(DynamicHub.java:1026)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.Packer.getStaticField(Packer.java:100)
    ... 33 more

I try to add this reflect-config, but error occurs again:
[
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.avro.SpecificDataSupplier",
    "allPublicConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.plain.BooleanPlainValuesWriter",
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.LemireBitPackingBE",
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.Packer",
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredClasses" : true
  }
]

I'm struggling to solve this issue.
Do you know if it's possible to write a Parquet file with a GraalVM native image? If yes, what did I miss?

Idk why this was downvoted. There  are no many docus about native. The reflect-json.config in the solution is helpful and insightful

I missed this property in my reflect-config.json file:
"fields" : [
  { "name" : "factory" }
]

So, I fixed my issue with this reflect-config.json content:
[
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.avro.SpecificDataSupplier",
    "allPublicConstructors" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.LemireBitPackingBE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.LemireBitPackingLE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.ByteBitPackingBE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.ByteBitPackingLE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.ByteBitPackingForLongBE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.parquet.column.values.bitpacking.ByteBitPackingForLongLE",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "factory" }
    ]
  }
]

